# Cannot add ppa:ondrej/nginx-mainline on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apt

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 (impish flavor) and have just installed PHP 8.1 using Ondrej's PPA.

As recommended, I'd also like to use [Ondrej's Nginx PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/nginx) to get the latest mainline version and benefit from Brotli support and TLS 1.3 among other improvements.

It seems this PPA isn't available for the `impish` flavor though?

```
#:/etc/apt# add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/nginx-mainline
[...]
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/nginx-mainline/ubuntu impish Release
  404  Not Found
```

Am I missing something here? Should I use the `hirsute` package instead [as suggested on their Issue tracker](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1662)?

Comment: Note that if you use Cloudflare (or other pull-type CDN), the improvements like Brotli support and TLS 1.3 will largely be void as they are implemented on the Cloudflare side.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin Agreed. I ended up going with the 1.20 version and gzip + Cloudflare for brotli.